# Calculate this Eccentricity of a hyperbola with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, geometry

How to calculate the `Eccentricity e`?

$F_1, F_2$ are the left focus and right focus respectively of the hyperbola:$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1$( a > 0 , b > 0). Point P is on the right branch of the hyperbola, $(\overrightarrow{OP} +\overrightarrow{OF_2})\cdot  \overrightarrow{PF_2}=0$, and O is the origin. $ \| PF_1\| = \sqrt{3} \cdot\| PF_2\| $. Calculate the eccentricity e.

I believe `Eccentricity e` is numeric

```
  Reduce[x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1 && x >= a && a > 0 && b > 0 && 
  c^2 == a^2 + b^2 && ({x, y} + {c, 0}).{c - x, -y} == 0 &&
  EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {-c, 0}] == 
   Sqrt[3] EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {c, 0}] && e == c/a, {a, b, x, y,
   e}, Reals]
```

**But I can't get the  numeric result through the code I put on here.**

*What's wrong with my code?*

Comment: Do you have a link for the eccentricity? What's the context? I'm sure many people I know would say I have an eccentricity > 0, but I doubt that is what you're going for

Comment: @b3m2a1, I have edited the question and given you the context.

Comment: `Reduce` doesn't return numbers...? Why not just turn the expression for the eccentricity into a function?

Comment: @b3m2a1, how can I turn the eccentricity into a function? Any example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is very close.  Use `Eliminate` on your system of equations, then `Solve` for the eccentricity, like this

```
system = {
    x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1 &&
    c^2 == a^2 + b^2 &&
    ({x, y} + {c, 0}).{c - x, -y} == 0 &&

    EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {-c, 0}] == 
     Sqrt[3] EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {c, 0}] &&

    e == c/a};

First@Solve[{Eliminate[system, {b, x, y, c, a}], e > 1}, e]

(*  {e -> 1 + Sqrt[3]}  *)
```

Comment: Also, `Simplify[Solve[
   x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1 && x >= a && a > 0 && b > 0 && 
    c^2 == a^2 + b^2 && ({x, y} + {c, 0}).{c - x, -y} == 0 && 
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {-c, 0}] == 
     Sqrt[3] EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {c, 0}] && e == c/a && e > 0, 
   e, {a, b, x, y}, Reals][[1]], c > 0]`